# Is this a puzzle? If so, what is the solution?

Tags: english, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

In the [2032th xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/2032/) Cueball utters a sentence that may (and probably does) contain a word puzzle.

> [image: transcription below]
>
> [Cueball and Megan standing together, musical notes hanging in the air as if music is played]
>   Cueball: Parts of this aria were composed by Brian Eno's opera star au pair at the start of his post-live era.
>   Megan (thinking): ...parts...start...eno...aria...
>   [Caption:] My hobby: Messing with word game enthusiasts by using words that make them ***sure*** there's a puzzle to solve

The title text (which may or may not contain a puzzle) reads:

> Eno's storied aria was once soloed by judge Lance Ito on the alto oboe at Ohio's AirAsia Arena.

**Is this indeed a puzzle and if so, what is its solution?**

Comment: I’m not sure whether to be amused at the fact that this proves Randall’s methods of riling up a puzzler or simply intrigued...but darn it if I’m not curious myself as to the answer to this question!

Comment: I'm amused at Randall's curious notion as to what will mess with a wordplay fan. It's not as if Cueball's words sound like a riddle or a crossword clue.

Comment: I see no reason to believe this is a puzzle: it's simply a bunch of words that commonly appear in crosswords.

Comment: There's an unusually high number of words starting with "a" and "o": ("of"), "aria", "opera", "au pair", ("at") and ("of") and even more in the title text: "aria", "once", ("on"), "alto oboe at Ohio's AirAsia Arena". The bottom text on the other hand contains only one word that starts with "a" and that is "a" and pretty hard to avoid. I would suspect something in binary, A being the 1st character of the alphabet and O looking like 0, but there's not enough information for a meaningful hidden message.

Comment: The title text, 100101011, is 299, one less than 300. 101011 is 43, one more than 42. There are 16 words with A and O in the comic and title text, decoded as ASCII they give `[+`. Doing the same with the entire transcript also results in nothing helpful. Using every A and O in the visible text gives nothing as well. Using the entire transcript results in `õû'ç¸Ü`. There's an unusually high number of modified "u"s in there… No, just kidding, this is a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do not think this is a puzzle, as he says "I like messing with word game enthusiasts by using words that make them sure there's a puzzle", and he wouldn't be messing with them if there was a puzzle.

Correct me if you've found a puzzle, as currently everyone just thinks there's no puzzle at all. As Deusovi says, "I see no reason to believe this is puzzle: it's simply a bunch of words that commonly appear in crosswords."